# Add one line to the cell when enter is pressed

Tags: php, fpdf

So I just detected a problem on my fpdf, when I'm writing the description to the multicell I press enter to break line and this happens

[Image with problem](https://prnt.sc/no0jlf)

but my multicell code is programmed to calculate the string size and when the size is bigger than the width of the cell it ads one break line and the height size gets bigger but when I press enter it just add the same height
example

"My name is João" -> height = 6.5

"My name is João, (*line break*) I'm using fpdf" -> height = 6.5 + 6.5 instead of height = 6.5 + 1

this is my pdf without pressing enter

[Image](http://prntscr.com/no0mf4)

this is my pdf with multicell on action

[Image](http://prntscr.com/no0qoa)

I will leave the code that it's calculating all the multicell stuff.

```php
$size = $pdf-> h;  // page size

$cellWidth=120;   // width da cell
$cellHeight=6.5;  // height da cell

// verificar se o texto passa a cell

if($pdf->GetStringWidth(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$r['description'])) < $cellWidth){
       //doesn't do anything because when line is multiplied it receives the same value ( 6.5 * 1 = 6.5 )
      $line = 1;
}else{
       $line = ceil($pdf->GetStringWidth(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$r['description'])));
       $line = round($line / $cellWidth,0) + 1;
}

// use multicell instead of cell
// as a MultiCell is always treated as end of line, 
// manually set the xy position to the next cell being next.
// save a position x before writing a multicell

$xPos=$pdf->GetX();
$yPos=$pdf->GetY();
$total = $yPos + ($line * $cellHeight);

if ($total > $size - 30) { // $size = $totalheight // change page
       $pdf->AddPage();      // add page
       $xPos=$pdf->GetX();
       $yPos=$pdf->GetY();
}
$sizecell = $pdf->GetMultiCellHeight($cellWidth, $cellHeight,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$r['description']));
$pdf->MultiCell($cellWidth,$cellHeight,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$r['description']),'LBR','L');



// receive the position of the cell after multicell
// equals the x with the height of the multicell
$pdf->SetXY($xPos + $cellWidth , $yPos);
// write cells


// as the variable $cellHeight is multiplied by the value of the line is going to be greater than $cellHeight
// of the multicell so we need to make a loop and subtract 0.01 until the value is the same as the multicell

$cell = $line * $cellHeight;


if ($cell > $sizecell){
   while($cell > $sizecell){
        $cell = $cell - 0.01;
   }
} else {
   $cell = $cell;
}

$pdf->Cell(15,($cell),$r['quantity'],'LBR',0);          
$pdf->Cell(10,($cell),'UNI','LBR',0);
$pdf->Cell(25,($cell),$r['priceuni'].chr(128),'LBR',0);
$pdf->Cell(25,($cell),$r['sum'].chr(128),'LBR',1);
```

I accept any suggestions, I have no idea of how am I going to do this

Comment: You will need to check the string specifically for a line break (which could be several things) and adjust accordingly. `stripos` might help you in this case.

Comment: @Dave how am I going to use `stripos`?

Comment: Actually `substr_count` would probably be a better option. If your string uses `/r/n` for example this sample will echo a value of 2 which means you need to add room for 2 additional lines. `$test = "This is a\r\ntest string with a crnl in it\r\n";
echo  substr_count($test,"\r\n");`

Comment: Oh, I think I get it that will counts if it has more than one string if yes what can I do?

Comment: Increase the height of your cell. You're already doing the math to get the height so adjust it accordingly if there are breaks in the text. Or remove the breaks from the text and use the logic you already have.

Comment: I will try to Increase the height. The purpose is to add a break if I press enter so I think I can do it. Thanks! I will inform you the result.

Comment: I added this to my if statement `substr_count(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$r['descricao']),"\r\n") >= 1` so the result of the if statement is this [print](http://prntscr.com/norj07) and I think I know why it's not working.. It's because when I do press enter in the input it doesn't receive `\r\n` in the output [output](http://prntscr.com/norjor) it's just a blank space..

Comment: I can't increase the height if I don't know the value of ENTER

Comment: Where is that enter coming from? As I mentioned earlier on a Windows system it is normally CRLF (\r\n) but it may be different on other platforms on when using other methods (such as a form on a web page).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193378/discussion-between-joao-neves-and-dave).